# Weird glitches after unlocking on 20.10

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Sometimes after unlocking my laptop, I get weird graphical glitches when changing windows. I have a Dell Precision 5530 with a Nvidia P2000. I'm using the latest Nvidia drivers (455) with the Intel graphics selected. I've tested several earlier versions as well as the Nouveau driver and had the same issue. Closing all windows doesn't help, but logging in and out does.

I can't find anyone with the same issue. Is there any diagnostics I can run while this happens to figure out a root cause? It happens pretty consistently during regular usage.

Comment: yeah me too, I was thinking that problem is with my hardware but now if you are having the same then it can be some sort of problem

Comment: Are you using the Intel graphics card or the nvidia graphics card? If intel, then adding the boot parameter i915.enable_psr=0 may help (at the expence of some more battery use).